# ESLint --fix not editing files

Tags: javascript, lint, eslint

I am trying to lint and fix my code using ESLint. 
When I run ESLint with my config file and without the fix flag, it runs fine, and this is what it outputs.

eslint-c .eslintrc.json ./src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers

```
/home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersController.js
    8:9   error  Unexpected blank line after variable declarations  newline-after-var
   15:13  error  'hlp' is defined but never used                    no-unused-vars
   50:30  error  'helper' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   55:32  error  'helper' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   59:42  error  'helper' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   69:7   error  Expected { after 'if' condition                    curly
   69:22  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                eqeqeq
   71:22  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                eqeqeq
   76:22  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                eqeqeq
   84:50  error  Object properties must go on a new line            object-property-newline
   89:21  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                eqeqeq
  113:27  error  'appEvent' is already defined                      no-redeclare

/home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersHelper.js
  14:17  error  Gratuitous parentheses around expression  no-extra-parens
  23:17  error  'appEvent' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
  24:28  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='       eqeqeq
  28:28  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='       eqeqeq
  32:28  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='       eqeqeq
```

All of that information is correct, and are issues that must be fixed in the code.
So I run it again, this time with

eslint --fix --debug -c .eslintrc.json ./src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers

Now the output is

```
eslint:cli Running on files +0ms
  eslint:config Using command line config .eslintrc.json +70ms
  eslint:config-file Loading JSON config file: /home/jason/sfa/testproj/.eslintrc.json +5ms
  eslint:config-file Loading /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/conf/eslint.json +292ms
  eslint:config-file Loading JSON config file: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/conf/eslint.json +0ms
  eslint:ignored-paths Looking for ignore file in /home/jason/sfa/testproj +40ms
  eslint:ignored-paths Could not find ignore file in cwd +0ms
  eslint:glob-util Creating list of files to process. +1ms
  eslint:cli-engine Processing /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersController.js +6ms
  eslint:cli-engine Linting /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersController.js +1ms
  eslint:config Constructing config for /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersController.js +0ms
  eslint:config Using .eslintrc and package.json files +0ms
  eslint:config Loading /home/jason/sfa/testproj/.eslintrc.yml +2ms
  eslint:config-file Loading YAML config file: /home/jason/sfa/testproj/.eslintrc.yml +1ms
  eslint:config-file Loading /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/conf/eslint.json +63ms
  eslint:config-file Loading JSON config file: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/conf/eslint.json +0ms
  eslint:config Using /home/jason/sfa/testproj/.eslintrc.yml +5ms
  eslint:config Merging command line config file +0ms
  eslint:config Merging command line environment settings +0ms
  eslint:config-ops Apply environment settings to config +1ms
  eslint:config-ops Creating config for environment browser +0ms
  eslint:cli-engine Linting code for /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersController.js (pass 1) +3ms
  eslint:cli-engine Generating fixed text for /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersController.js (pass 1) +147ms
  eslint:text-fixer Applying fixes +0ms
  eslint:text-fixer No fixes to apply +0ms
  eslint:cli-engine Processing /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersHelper.js +0ms
  eslint:cli-engine Linting /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersHelper.js +1ms
  eslint:config Constructing config for /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersHelper.js +0ms
  eslint:config Using config from cache +0ms
  eslint:cli-engine Linting code for /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersHelper.js (pass 1) +0ms
  eslint:cli-engine Generating fixed text for /home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersHelper.js (pass 1) +56ms
  eslint:text-fixer Applying fixes +0ms
  eslint:text-fixer No fixes to apply +0ms
  eslint:cli-engine Linting complete in: 291ms +1ms
  eslint:cli Fix mode enabled - applying fixes +0ms

/home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersController.js
    8:9   error  Unexpected blank line after variable declarations  newline-after-var
   15:13  error  'hlp' is defined but never used                    no-unused-vars
   50:30  error  'helper' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   55:32  error  'helper' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   59:42  error  'helper' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
   69:7   error  Expected { after 'if' condition                    curly
   69:22  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                eqeqeq
   71:22  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                eqeqeq
   76:22  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                eqeqeq
   84:50  error  Object properties must go on a new line            object-property-newline
   89:21  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                eqeqeq
  113:27  error  'appEvent' is already defined                      no-redeclare

/home/jason/sfa/testproj/src/aura/SearchAvailableNumbers/SearchAvailableNumbersHelper.js
  14:17  error  Gratuitous parentheses around expression  no-extra-parens
  23:17  error  'appEvent' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
  24:28  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='       eqeqeq
  28:28  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='       eqeqeq
  32:28  error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='       eqeqeq

✖ 17 problems (17 errors, 0 warnings)
```

When I open the actual code, nothing has been changed. When I run the linter again, it outputs the same thing.

It clearly says "generating fixed text" but then it outputs "no fixes to apply". I can't find anything regarding how the fix flag functions online, so I turn to stackoverflow for help.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not all of the ESLint rules are fixable (actually most of the rules are not fixable as of yet). You can find out which rules can be autofixed by looking for wrench glyph on this page: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/

None of the rules that you have errors for are currently autofixable. Some because the ESLint team hasn't gotten to them yet (like `newline-after-var`), some, because it's very likely to create a different logic then was intended in the original code (like `eqeqeq`) and some, because it's impossible to figure out the right way to autofix it (like `no-unused-vars` and `no-redeclare`)

Comment: Kinda lame that eslint can't fix e.g. an unsed argument error

Comment: Why is it not possible to autofix `no-unused vars`? Couldn't eslint just remove all unused vars?

Comment: Because it's not possible to be completely sure that the variable is not in-use using static analysis. There are just too many ways you can use a variable in JavaScript. Also, what if you just mistyped variable name in a place you were using it? ESLint autofixes go by the principle of "do no harm". It only changes the code if it's 100% sure that the change will not result in a different behavior.